# Is it possible to change automatically the font size of the labels which are not shown in the current map canvas on print composer?

Tags: qgis, labeling, style

I would like to make a rule-base labelling *depend on: is a label shown* in the current view or not. ("Show all labels for this layer (including colliding labels)" is unchecked.)

I would like to use it on a polyline layer, with curved placement.

For example:
The default font is 8p. If a label is not shown on the current view (because of colliding labels, I think), then the font size of that label changes to 7p, so it may come to be shown. If it does't, the font size of it changes to 6p, etc.